# Django queryset update() in += way

Tags: python, django

How can I call update on Django queryset, that does not write particular value, but modify the value already there, as follows

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2010).update(count+=1)
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) from docs:

> reporter = Reporters.objects.filter(name='Tintin')
>
> reporter.update(stories_filed=F('stories_filed') + 1)

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import F
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2010).update(count=F('count') + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for e in Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2010):
    e.count+= 1
    e.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is obvious and I would prefer to avoid the for loop with the update.

Answer (score 1):

**Pay attention to:**

if you are using F-expression - you are using `.update()` method.

If you have a needed logic in the overridden `.save()` method - it won't be called in such updating.

To use the `.save()` method you need to use a general approach:

```py
foo.bar += 1
foo.save()
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#update):

> Finally, realize that update() does an update at the SQL level and,
> thus, does not call any save() methods on your models, nor does it
> emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of
> calling Model.save()